# ASP.NET positioning within dropdownlist not working in some browers when entering repeating numbers (22, 33, etc)

Tags: asp.net, drop-down-menu, cross-browser

I have an asp.net dropdownlist control containing a list of numbers 1-36.  In most cases if the user types a number in the dropdownlist the corresponding number is highlighted.  In IE, the user can type any of the numbers (1-36) and the corresponding number is highlighted in the list.  In Chrome and Firefox, however, if a user types a number that has repeating values (22 and 33 for example) an incorrect value is highlighted.  22 will highlight 20 and 33 highlights 30.  I'm curious why this is happening and how I might work around it?

Comment: There is a way to make it work in Firefox with some Javascript code. The same code works in Chrome but only when typing in the closed box (when the element has the focus but the list is not displayed). When the list is opened in Chrome, I don't think that anything can be done because the key events cannot be detected. If my partial solution is of any interest to you, I can post an answer.

Comment: Yes, I'd be interested in seeing how you've handled it in Firefox.